How to access saved token in Pinia on SSR api calls?
I am fairly new with Quasar .
after login I save user data (including token ) on pinia auth store
// login-page.vue

function login(){
   const response= loginApi(/* user and pass */)
   authStore.user=response.data
}


an I also use pinia-plugin-persistedstate to persist Pinia states .
// /stores/auth.ts

import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { LoginResponse } from 'src/types/login';
import { ref } from 'vue';

// init
const user = ref<LoginResponse | null>(null);
const returnUrl = ref<string | null>(null);

export const useAuthStore = defineStore(
  'auth',
  () => {
    return { user ,returnUrl};
  },
  { persist: true }
);


also I have created axios boot file like this :
// /boot/axios.ts

import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { useToast } from 'src/composable/useNotify';
import { useAuthStore } from 'src/stores/auth';
// init
const { danger } = useToast();

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
    $api: AxiosInstance;
  }
}


let api: AxiosInstance;

export default boot(({ app,store }) => {
  api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000/api' });
  const authStore=useAuthStore(store)

  // set token
  console.log('authStore',authStore.user) // ** return null on server
  api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {


    const accessToken=authStore.user?.access_token

    if (accessToken) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
    }

    return config;
  });
  api.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {

      return response;
    },
    function (error) {

      danger('something went wrong');
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;

  app.config.globalProperties.$api = api;

});

export { api };


the problem is here ,
after login .
when I refresh some SSR page .
I expect for token be set for SSR Api calls
But it is not ,
it seems authStore.user is empty on server

above image show vscode console .
and it shows user is null
but on clinet it is ok as see below .

what is the problem ?
and how can I fix it ?

You don't show where and when "login" is called. It's unknown how auth state is persisted. But client-only auth is a usual thing. You probably don't have to fix it, depending on your expectations from SSR

login happens when user click on submit on login page .
login function get user data (including token) and save it on authStore as shown .
and suthStore is persisted using a package pinia-plugin-persistedstate

The plugin uses browser storage. Means there's no way how a token could be available on server side without you explicitly passing it from client side (or change the storage to non-http-only cookies). What you have is normal situation, as said. If you want to change it, you need a reasoning why you need this. In most cases there'd be none
